# Regular Expression - Return all matches as a single match

Tags: java, regex

I'm working with a piece of code that applies a regex to a string and returns the first match. I don't have access to modify the code to return all matches, nor do I have the ability to implement alternative code.

I have the following example target string:

> usera,userb,,userc,,userd,usere,userf,

This is a list of comma delimited usernames joined from multiple sources, some of which were blank resulting in two commas in some places. I'm trying to write a regex that will return all of the comma delimited usernames except for specific values.

For example, consider the following expression:

```
[^,]\w{1,},(?<!(userb|userc|userd),)
```

> This results in three matches:
>
> usera,
>
> usere,
>
> userf,

Is there any way to get these results as a single match, instead of a match collection, e.g. a single match having the text 'usera,usere,userf,' ?

If I could write code in any language this would be trivial, but I'm limited to input of only the target string and the pattern, and I need a single match that has all items except for the ones I'm omitting. I'm not sure if this is even possible, everything I've ever done with regex's involves processing multiple items in a match collection.

Here is an example in Regex Coach. This image shows that there are the three matches I want, but my requirement is to have the text in a single match, not three separate matches.

[image]

**EDIT1:**
To clarify this ticket is specifically intended to solve the use case using only regular expression syntax. Solving this problem in code is trivial but solving it using only a regex was the requirement given the fact that the executing code is part of a 3rd party product that I didn't want to reverse engineer, wrap, or replace.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Regular expressions aren't a complete language; it may be extraordinarily difficult to get what you want without any supporting code in a real language.

Comment: The regex is being processed in JAVA, so it will follow JAVA's processing rules, but I don't have access to the underlying code to modify it. This is part of a utility with very specific inputs that I can't modify

Comment: @Eric. In that case, you can make use of `StringBuilder` to create the required string out of all the matches. It would be far easier.

Comment: Since a "match" is a *single* substring selection, it cannot jump over the excluded ones - the answer is No

Comment: @Rohit - Unfortunately I don't have access to any of the JAVA code itself. If I could rewrite this it would be an easy problem to solve but unfortunately I'm dealing with compiled code so I'm limited to only what I can do with a single RegEx. 

I researched a lot and didn't think this would be possible to do using nothing but RegEx syntax, but was hoping I missed something

Comment: @Eric: You can use a decompiler to decompile the class (there are free one around on the net). Java bytecode is very easy to be decompiled to the original Java code. The 1st/2nd result return this: http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui

Comment: Thanks @nhahtdh but this is a 3rd party JIRA plugin (written in JAVA) that I wanted to try to implement without modifying it. Getting the source code, or writing my own code is not an issue. I was hoping to use it as is, but it doesn't seem possible. Ruling out using a single regex I can move onto one of many alternatives

Comment: @Eric See my modified answer. Maybe that's a way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to get these results as a single match, instead of a match collection, e.g. a single match having the text `'usera,usere,userf,'`?

No. Regex matches are consecutive.

A regular expression matches a (sub)string from start to finish. You cannot drop the middle part, this is not how regex engines work. But you can apply the expression again to find another matching substring (incremental search - that's what Regex Coach does). This would result in a match collection.

---

That being said, you could also just match everything you *don't* want to keep and remove it, e.g.

```
,(?=[\s,]+)|(userb|userc|userd)[\s,]*
```

http://rubular.com/r/LOKOg6IeBa